# ProxyFactoryBean uses JdkDynamicAopProxy instead of CGLIB

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to configure a `ProxyFactoryBean` with a `ThreadLocalTargetSource` for `SimpleDateFormat` objects.
As you can see in the image

[image: Immagine.png]

Spring AOP is not using CGLIB to proxy `SimpleDateFormat`, and so it returns `ConversionNotSupportedException` when it tries to verify the compatibility with `SimpleDateFormat`.

I cannot understand what it is doing. I've been debugging since a couple of hours and I can't understand.
What do you guys think? What am I doing wrong? Am I missing dependencies?

The Spring `@Configuration` is done as follow

```
@Bean("yyyyMMdd")
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public DateFormat simpleDateFormatYyyyMmDd() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
public ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalYyyyMmDd() {
    final ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalTargetSource = new ThreadLocalTargetSource();
    threadLocalTargetSource.setTargetBeanName("yyyyMMdd");
    return threadLocalTargetSource;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public ProxyFactoryBean proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource(final ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalTargetSource) {
    final ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactoryBean.setTargetSource(threadLocalTargetSource);
    return proxyFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Done. Thanks for the remainder. I was too much in a hurry

Comment: Just `setProxyTargetClass` to `true` in the `ProxyFactoryBean`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that was it. I had even read the XML alternative this morning and I totally forgot... Basically, being the default at false, if it finds interfaces it implements them and not the class directly, so that's why it uses the Jdk alternative.
A bit off topic but why would I need to use a ProxyFactory when I can define a SimpleThreadScope with a custom scope? They're both using ThreadLocal in the end, so what's the proxy advantage?

Comment: Why even bother with scope or target sources? Why not simply use the `ThreadLocal` yourself and let that handle the creation of the thread local? Using this for simple things like a `SimpleDateFormat` seems like overkill for this feature.

Comment: It's a bit overkill undoubtedly. But autowiring is handy, and if in the future I'll switch to an object pool it will be easier. What I'm worried about is memory consumption

Comment: Using thread scope will create an instance for each thread and discard when the thread dies. Using a thread local will reuse te instance. (The thread scope will also if the thread never dies!). However using a thread local directly here is probably easier and more readable. Or ditch this all together and use the java8 date time api in which the formatter is thread safe.

Comment: I'm on Java 6, that's why. And do not assume people remember DateFormat is not safe. I think I will have to let the application run and somehow inspect the threadlocal storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for future myself, just in case:

Read this Spring documentation paragraph https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies

As @SotiriosDelimanolis wrote, to force the use of `CGLIB` a call to `setProxyTargetClass(true)` on the `ProxyFactoryBean` object is needed.